Add = first in every cell
I have imported lots of data from another program where large numbers where written as 4565E5 for example. If I add an = in front Google Sheets recognises it as an exponential and makes it into 4565*10^5 like I want, but I can't manually write an = in front of every cell. Is there a good way to do this easily?
Just any way of making these "strings" into numbers.

You can use some smarted text editor and use regex to replace any first character with itself plus =

well it wont let me upload without enough text and i didnt want to make you read more than necessary

You may have added sample input data instead of random text

@justinas smarted text editor? what is that?

E.g. Notepad++ or Sublime

Can you use that with Google Sheets though?


Use the  Find & replace option (available under Edit menu options)
find ^
replace =
tick search using regular expressions & click Replace/all


using regex, simply replacing the first character as =
